# How many functions can be defined between two sets, given two conditions?

Tags: combinatorics

*This is taken from Cambridge University's Computer Science Admissions Test (CSAT), [Sample Paper 3](https://csat.io/sample-test-3.pdf), Question 19:*

> Let $A=\{0, 1, \dots, 2^n-1,2^n\}$ and $B=\{0,\dots,n\}$. How many functions $g$ can be defined from $A$ to $B$ such that both of the following conditions hold:
>
> - for all $x\in{}B$ we have $g(2^x)=x$,
> - for all $y,z\in{}A$ with $y\le{}z$ we have $g(y)\le{}g(z)$.

I'm having difficulty with understanding the question, specifically the first condition. I'm aware that, generally, for sets $A_n=\{a_1,\dots{},a_n\}$ and $B_k=\{b_1,\dots{},b_k\}$, there exist $k^n$ such functions from $A_n\rightarrow{}B_k$, but that's about all I can contribute.

Comment: Hi. Welcome. What have you done?

Comment: @Cornman No, it is presented exactly as-is from the sample paper.

Comment: To give you an example, for $n = 3$, we have that $A = \{0,...,8\}, B = \{0,...,3\}$ and $g(1) = 0, g(2) = 1, g(4) = 2$ and $g(8) = 3$. Also, $g$ is monotonically increasing. Keeping both of these conditions in mind, there aren't too many possibilities left for $2^x < z < 2^{x+1}$.

Comment: The first condition is explicitly telling you the value of $g$ at every power of two. That means the only freedom you have in defining $g$ is at elements of $A$ that aren't powers of two. Now try to think about what the second condition tells you about where you can send those elements that aren't powers of two.

Comment: @Sudix Thank you, edited.

Comment: I think the total is $2^{n(n-1)/2}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you notice, there are that many for a general rule, but here you have to fix your numbers $2^x.$ notice that there are $n+1$ numbers like this i.e., $1,2,\cdots, 2^{n}$ and so extract $\underbrace{2^k+1,2^k+2,\cdots ,2^{k+1}-1}_{2^{k+1}-1-(2^k+1)+1\text{numbers}}$ for some $k<n,$ this numbers can go to either $k$ or $k+1$ by the condition hence the only thing we have to find is where do we stop using $k$ as the image and start using $k+1$, which is in any of this numbers or exactly in $2^k$ so there are $2^{k+1}-2^k-1+1$ options. Doing this for all the $k'$s and using the product rule, you will get something like $\prod _{k=0}^{n-1}(2^{k+1}-2^k)=2^{\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}k}=2^{\binom{n}{2}}.$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I generally understand, but it's a little too vague for me around the "and so extract" part.

Comment: i edited, hopefully is better

Comment: It took me a long while to read and understand this, but now I do, it's really beautiful! Thank you for sharing. Is there an area of mathematics / lemma that this line of reasoning stems from?

Comment: You are welcome. I guess Enumeration in general. There are good books from Martin Aigner in enumeration.